# Powershell : How to unstall Windows applications (for example XBox Live, Sticky Notes, Microsoft Teams, ...) using powershell scripts and silently

Tags: powershell, scripting, uninstallation

I have tried different scripts to uninstall some applications. But Nothing works as espected.

For example :

```
$programName = "Sticky Notes"
$uninstallQuery = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name LIKE '%$programName%'"

if ($uninstallQuery -ne $null) {
    $uninstallQuery.Uninstall()
    Write-Host "$programName uninstalled successfully."
} else {
    Write-Host "$programName not found on the system."
}
```

returns nothing

*Sticky Notes not found on the system.*

And the application exist.

[image: Snap shot of applications list]

Do you have some working scripts in powershell to uninstall applications in windows 11 ?

BR

Jeronimo